# Hibernate select parents with list of childs matches child parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following structure: **Bank** has name and **list of Offices**. **Office** has **city** property.

How can i select **Banks** with their own lists of **Offices** only with particular **city** using hql?

Code:
**Bank**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANKS")
public class Bank {
    public Bank() {
    }

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    /*@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)*/
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bank", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    /*@JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")*/
    private List<Office> officeList;
```

**Office**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFICES")
public class Office {
    public Office() {
    }

    public Office(String city, String address, String workingHours, Bank bank) {
        this.city = city;
        this.address = address;
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Bank bank;

    public void setBank(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public Bank getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "WORKING_HOURS")
    private String workingHours;
```

I've wrote request but it works wrong:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select b from Bank b join b.officeList o" +
                "    where o.city = ?").setString(0, city).list();
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you must add your sql code and show us your effort until now

Comment: That query looks like it should work.  Is it returning an empty list or is it throwing an exception?

Comment: @Pace, it returns every list of Banks which list of offices contains at least one office with required city, and if Bank's office list contains two or more matching elements, this bank will be returned same times. But i need result to contain BankList with OfficeLists containing only matching property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first point, duplicates are expected because you join with a collection, and you can easily eliminate them with `distinct`:

```
select distinct b from Bank b join b.officeList o where o.city = :city
```

The second point (that `officeList` contains only the matching property) is conceptually much more trickier.

The point is that during initialization of the `officeList` collection for a `Bank` instance, Hibernate loads all the offices associated with the corresponding bank. That's what Hibernate is supposed to do: to reflect the database state in the object graph. That has nothing to do which entities/tables you joined and which `where` conditions you specified in the original query you used to retrieve the bank.

However, there is the ability to initialize children associations in the same query in which you load parents by using the `[left] join fetch` construct. For example, to load all banks together with all their offices in one query you can do:

```
select distinct b from Bank b left join fetch b.officeList
```

Hibernate supports aliasing and using the `fetch` joined entities further in the `where` condition. This way you are basically initializing the collection only with the subset of the elements that are in the database. So, to achieve what you need you could change your query to:

```
select distinct b from Bank b join fetch b.officeList o where o.city = :city
```

However, keep in mind that using `fetch` joined associations in filtering conditions in queries is not supported by the JPA specification. Also, you should investigate what the impact on the second-level cache is if you use it and this collection is cached there.

Comment: Hello, sir. Thank you for detailed answer, even i was able to understand this ^^. It works perfectly.